# What is the C# equivalent to Java's isInstance()?

Tags: c#, reflection, introspection, instanceof

I know of `is` and `as` for `instanceof`, but what about the reflective [isInstance()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) method?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The equivalent of Java’s `obj.getClass().isInstance(otherObj)` in C# is as follows:

```
bool result = obj.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(otherObj.GetType());
```

Note that while both Java and C# work on the runtime type object (Java `java.lang.Class` ≣ C# `System.Type`) of an `obj` (via `.getClass()` vs `.getType()`), Java’s `isInstance` takes an object as its argument, whereas C#’s `IsAssignableFrom` expects another `System.Type` object.

Comment: Note IsAssignableFrom takes a Type, not an object, so you need to actually do OtherObj.getType().

Comment: Thanks Jon – and remember, this is a wiki! I don't resent people correcting my mistakes.

Comment: interesting... in java, the JVM treats "instanceof" specially, apparently its very very fast, which may explain why its unusually a keyword (there is also an isAssignable method in java).

Comment: Why is this method better then the "is" operator which is more readable?

Comment: @TimothyGonzalez Because it does something different. It tests whether two *variables* have the same type. `is` required a type name, by contrast. This is what OP wanted: the equivalent of Java's `isInstance`. The other answer is simply wrong despite the ridiculous number of upvotes.

Answer (score 193):

```
bool result = (obj is MyClass); // Better than using 'as'
```

Comment: Does it work even for classes that use inheritance? (`new Child() is Parent`)

Comment: tested here, it works for classes that user inheritance. Thanks man.

Answer (score 39):

Depends, use `is` if you don't want to use the result of the cast and use `as` if you do. You hardly ever want to write:

```
if(foo is Bar) {
    return (Bar)foo;
}
```

Instead of:

```
var bar = foo as Bar;
if(bar != null) {
    return bar;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just off the top of my head, you could also do:

```
bool result = ((obj as MyClass) != null)
```

Not sure which would perform better. I'll leave it up to someone else to benchmark :)

Answer (score 2):

Below code can be alternative to `IsAssignableFrom`.

```
parentObject.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(inheritedObject)
```

See [Type.IsInstanceOfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) description in MSDN.