# What is the VB equivalent of Java's instanceof and isInstance()?

Tags: java, vb.net, reflection, introspection, instanceof

In the spirit of the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282459/what-is-the-c-equivalent-to-javas-instanceof-and-isinstance) question..

What is the equivalent statements to compare class types in VB.NET?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you looking for something like `TypeOf`?  This only works with reference types, not int/etc.

```
If TypeOf "value" Is String Then
     Console.WriteLine("'tis a string, m'lord!")
```

Or do you want to compare two different instances of variables? Also works for ref types:

```
Dim one As Object = "not an object"
Dim two As Object = "also not an object, exactly"
Dim three as Object = 3D

If one.GetType.Equals( two.GetType ) Then WL("They are the same, man")
If one.GetType Is two.GetType then WL("Also the same")
If one.GetType IsNot three.GetType Then WL("but these aren't")
```

You could also use `gettype()` like thus, if you aren't using two objects:

```
If three.GetType Is gettype(integer) then WL("is int")
```

If you want to see if something is a subclass of another type (and are in .net 3.5):

```
If three.GetType.IsSubclassOf(gettype(Object)) then WL("it is")
```

But if you want to do that in the earlier versions, you have to flip it (weird to look at) and use:

```
If gettype(Object).IsAssignableFrom(three.GetType) Then WL("it is")
```

All of these compile in [SnippetCompiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/), so go DL if you don't have it.

Answer (score 4):

```
TypeOf obj Is MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when it was implemented but VB now has [Type.IsInstanceOfType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isinstanceoftype?view=net-6.0):

"Returns true if the current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of the object represented by o, or if the current Type is an interface that o implements..."

Example:

```
Dim arr(10) As Integer
If GetType(Array).IsInstanceOfType(arr) Then _
    Console.WriteLine("Is int[] an instance of the Array class? {0}.",
                       GetType(Array).IsInstanceOfType(arr))
```

Output: `Is int[] an instance of the Array class? True.`

Answer (score 0):

The VB equivalent to your linked question is almost identical:

```
Dim result As Boolean = obj.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(otherObj.GetType())
```