# c# test if a class is a subtype of another class

Tags: c#, inheritance

This will seem a lot like another post I made but I am writing a similar program in C#.
I have class Card and class Land which is a subclass of Card. In Java, I used `instanceof` to determine if it was a child of Card.
The object being referred to is held in the variable `c`
I have already tried:

```
if (typeof (Land).isSubClassOf(typeof(Card))){
//random code
}
```

What i'm trying to do, in java, would be:

```
if ( c instanceof Land){
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282459/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-instanceof-and-isinstance

Comment: `YourObject.GetType.IsAssignableFrom(YourParentClass.GetType());`

Comment: I think your question has created some confusion, which is why you're getting completely different answers. Do you have an *object* and you want to know if that object is of type `Card` or one of its subclasses, or do you have a `Type` and you want to know if that Type is a subtype of another type?

Comment: @Lapious I had not yet, but on trying it, it didn't work the way i needed it to

Comment: @ScottHannen I have an object, upon testing, the marked answer was the only to work the way it needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check for the type and *then* cast. If you do that you're really checking the type twice. Do this:

```
var l = c as Land;
```

If `c` can be cast as `Land` then `l` will contain that. If not it will be `null`.

If you do this:

```
if(c is Land)
    l = (Land)c;
```

Then you're actually inspecting `c` twice. Once to check whether it is of type `Land`, and then again to do the actual cast.

[C# As keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

Comment: The check is in the midst of an if statement, thus casting like that results in an error saying that I cannot implicitly cast Land to bool

Comment: using this method worked, mostly because i had forgotten that i had declared a variable to hold the type of Card, thus by checking directly to that variable, i was able to safely cast. the difference was made when other types of Card started coming into the program

Comment: This doesn't matter as much if we're just doing a boolean check - is it a given type? But 99% of the time if we need to know *if* it's a certain type then we're going to need to cast to that type. That's where `as` comes in, because we avoid checking and then casting.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(foo is Bar) {
    return (Bar)foo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For direct inheritance :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Land c = new Land();
    bool isCard = c.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Card));
}
```

Or:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Land c = new Land();
    bool isCard = c is Card;
}
```

Comment: I tried everything else that I saw and nothing worked. Thanks so much @user3185569

Comment: the main problem with this answer is that: Card has several descendants(Land, Spell, etc), in the used method, I pass a Card object. if I test the card to see if it is a land using this method isCard will always be true when what i wanted was to see if the card was a Land